# Why href is not working?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, href

I can't seem to figure out why the href links are not working. It was working just fine then all of the sudden it stopped working. I ran it through the validator and it passed. Below is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
              <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>

              <li><a id="clothing" href="#">Clothing</a></li>

              <li><a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>

              <li><a id="about" href="#">About Ism</a></li>

              <li><a id="music" href="#">Da Konglomerate&#36;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="banner">
            <img id="bannerImage" src="banner_slide/ism_logo1.png" alt="Ism Banner Slides" />
        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
          src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401" alt="Valid HTML 4.01 Strict" height="31" width="88"></a>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: which `a`(s) are not working and that is the actual issue, doesnt click? Path is wrong? etc.

Comment: Define "working" and "not working"

Comment: it does not click. i did not specify a path as im using jquery to have it load into link.

Comment: "then all of the sudden it stopped working" - this just doesn't happen. Something's changed. Likely by you.

Comment: i changed the name of the html file for one of the links, but i also changed the name in the jquery code

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the above HTML. It may be the javascript code to load the link to the `<a>` stopped working. Attach the code with proper comments to get help

Comment: first function loads home.html on load and the functions below load the corresponding html files when clicked into div

Comment: $(function(){ $("#content").load("home.html"); $("#home").on("click", function(){ $("#content").load("home.html"); }); $("#clothing").on("click", function(){ $("#content").load("clothing.html"); }); $("#contact").on("click", function(){ $("#content").load("contact.html"); }); $("#about").on("click", function(){ $("#content").load("about.html"); }); $("#music").on("click", function(){ $("#content").load("music.html"); })

Comment: Lol. Post it to the jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was due to my container div element which was in relative position and covered the link.